# How to show current clipboard in vuejs?

Tags: vuejs3, clipboard

I want to show the current clipboard live on a DIV. How can I archive that with VueJS?

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Clipboard</h1>
    <div>{{ clipboard }}</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: function () {
    return {
      clipboard: "clipborad:"

    }
  },
  methods: {
    async onChange() {
      const text = await navigator.clipboard.readText();
      console.log("clipboard: ", text)
      this.clipboard = text;
    }
  },

}
</script>
```

Basically, I need the code that listens to any clipboard changes, including those not within the browser. That can then call my `onChange` method.